# Gradle build doesn't produce compiled binary/class directory for Groovy source

Tags: groovy, gradle

Given the following `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'maven'

group = "myorg"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.3'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:1.3.2'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.5'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
}

artifacts {
    archives sourcesJar
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.11'
}

task dist(type: Zip, dependsOn: build) {
    classifier = 'buildreport'

    from('build/test-results') {
        include '*.xml'
        into 'tests'
    }

    from('build/reports/codenarc') {
        into 'reports'
    }

    from('build/docs') {
        into 'api'
    }

    from(sourcesJar) {
        into 'source'
    }

    from('build/libs') {
        exclude '*-sources.jar'
        into 'bin'
    }
}

task createPom << {

    pom {
        project {
            groupId "mygroup"
            artifactId "myservice-client"
            version version
        }
    }.writeTo("build/libs/pom.xml")
}
```

The following build invocation is not creating a `build/classes/**/*` directory:

```
gradle clean build sourcesJar createPom dist -Pversion=0.0.3
```

**Why?**

Comment: I created a gradle project with your build.gradle and added a groovy file under `src/main/groovy`; It got compiled and placed under `build/classes/` directory.

Comment: Perhaps the project doesn't have any Groovy code, or the code isn't located in `src/main/groovy`.

Comment: Thanks @PeterNiederwieser (+1) - you were correct, I only had my Groovy code under a `src/` directory. If you provide an answer with an explanation as to why Gradle requires `src/main/groovy` I'll happily give you the green check. Thanks again!

Comment: "If you provide an answer with an explanation as to why Gradle requires src/main/groovy..." - Gradle doesn't require that.  That is just the default.

Comment: Thanks @JeffScottBrown (+1) - then perhaps you could provide an answer that explains that, and perhaps how to configure Gradle and override the default, I would check that as well. Thanks again so much!

Comment: I am not going to do that. I didn't intend to hijack @PeterNiederwieser's answer.  This is all documented though.  See section 24.3.1 at http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/groovy_plugin.html#N12BC5 as an example.

Comment: Thanks @JeffScottBrown (+1 again) - however you would not be hijacking anyone's answer; Peter N. only provided a comment.